# Props vs Children to pass HTML content in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I need create a component to render like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="some another class">
            <h3>{{title}}</title>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p>{{contentA}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="some wrapper">
            <p>{{contentB}}</p>
        <div>
    </div>
<div>
```

It will receive the following data:

- **title** - a string
- **contentA** - a large string (paragraph), may contain
  links (a href)
- **contentB** - a large string or a complex HTML code

Here are the following methods I found. However, I'm not sure about which one is the recommended way by React.

#### Method 1

```
<Component title="a" contentA="some large content" contentB="another large content"/>
```

Pros: Easy to access different props in different sections of the component

Cons: Too complex  to handle if the content as large HTML content

#### Method 2

```
<Component>
    <title>a</title
    <content>some large content</content>
    <content>another large content</content>
</Component>
```

Pros: Much simpler code

Cons: Need to filter `props.children` and find each element to put in correct place in the component

Comment: The question is not complete.Please mention what are you trying to do

Comment: Sorry about that. I've fixed it

Answer (score 2):

**React** is all about creating granular components, the more granular you component tree is, you are doing it the more **React** way.

You say you get 3 things **text**,**contentA** and **ContentB**

**Title:** it's already granular.

**content A:** You say its a "***a large string (paragraph), may container links (a href)***"
, if its a paragraph it is granular but if its a collection of paragraphs, I think you should take that to a different component. **Ex: ContentA component**

**Content B:** This is clearly said that its a complex HTML code, that is what is React for, you need to break this complex HTML code into granular components which will make it more maintainable and it is a React best practice too.

have patience while breaking this into components, it's definitely worth it.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an accurate statement:

> Cons: Too complex to handle if the content as HTML contents

If a value can be held in a variable as a string, it can be used as an argument passed into your component.  If you don't want to be bothered trying to escape the quotes inside your prop values, I would encourage you to ditch the `<Component attr="someValue"/>` syntax and instead use `<Component attr={'someValue'}/>`.  This allows you to pass *variables* into your props.  This also allows you to use template literals to pass values, like so:

```
<Component
    title="a"
    contentA={`
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <p>Here is my super-big</p>
                <p>HTML-infused content</p>
                <p>I can even inject ${variables} in here!</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    `} 
    contentB="another large content"
/>
```

If you feel like that starts to clutter-up the declaration of your component, you can instead set those values in a variable and then pass them very cleanly into the component, as such:

```
render() {
    const bigHtmlContent = (
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <p>Here is my super-big</p>
                <p>HTML-infused content</p>
                <p>I can even inject {variables} in here!</p>
            </body>
        </html> 
    );
    return (
        <Component
            title="a"
            contentA={bigHtmlContent} 
            contentB="another large content"
        />  
    );
}
```

Of course, you can move the definition out of the `render()` function altogether if that suits you better:

```
getBigHtmlContent() {
    return (
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <p>Here is my super-big</p>
                <p>HTML-infused content</p>
                <p>I can even inject {variables} in here!</p>
            </body>
        </html>     
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <Component
            title="a"
            contentA={() => this.getBigHtmlContent()} 
            contentB="another large content"
        />  
    );
}
```

When I'm creating components, I tend to pass everything as props (as shown in the examples above).  I only use children if I'm creating a higher-order component which, by design, is supposed to act as a container for certain types of children.

For example, in Material UI there is a `<List>` component which requires one-or-more `<ListItem>`s.  In that case, I don't think it would make much sense to pass the `<ListItems>`s as props.  They are (and should be) children of the `<List>` component.